# How can I populate two tables from one database on JavaFx tableview

Tags: sql, database, javafx

I am new to JavaFx and database. I am trying to populate two or more tables from one database into JavaFx tableview. How can I do that? This is what I have so far.

1) this is my GeneralData.java

```
public class GeneralData {
    private final StringProperty Year;
    private final StringProperty Month;
    private final StringProperty Temperature;
    private final StringProperty Wind_Lowest;
    private final StringProperty Wind_Highest;
    private final StringProperty MinUVI;
    private final StringProperty MaxUVI;
    private final StringProperty MinAQI;
    private final StringProperty MaxAQI;
    private final StringProperty Humidity;
    private final StringProperty Snowfall;
    private final StringProperty Pressure;

    public GeneralData(String year, String month, String temperature, 
        String windlo, String Windhi,String minUVI, String maxUVI, String 
        minAQI, String maxAQI, String humidity, String snowfall, String 
        pressure){

        this.Year = new SimpleStringProperty(year);
        this.Month = new SimpleStringProperty(month);
        this.Temperature = new SimpleStringProperty(temperature);
        this.Wind_Lowest = new SimpleStringProperty(windlo);
        this.Wind_Highest= new SimpleStringProperty(Windhi);
        this.MinUVI = new SimpleStringProperty(minUVI);
        this.MaxUVI = new SimpleStringProperty(maxUVI);
        this.MinAQI = new SimpleStringProperty(minAQI);
        this.MaxAQI = new SimpleStringProperty(maxAQI);
        this.Humidity = new SimpleStringProperty(humidity);
        this.Snowfall = new SimpleStringProperty(snowfall);
        this.Pressure = new SimpleStringProperty(pressure);

    }
```

2) this is my GeneralMode.java

```
public class GeneralModel {
    Connection conn;

    public GeneralModel() {

        try {
            this.conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (this.conn == null) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public boolean isDatabasedConnected() {

        return this.conn != null;
    }

}
```

3) this is my generalController.java

```
public class GeneralController implements Initializable {


    GeneralModel generalModel = new GeneralModel();
    @FXML
    private Label dbStatus;

    @FXML
    private TextField miniField;
    @FXML
    private TextField maxField;

    @FXML
    private TableView<GeneralData> weatherTracerTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GeneralData, String> yearCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GeneralData, String> monthCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GeneralData, String> temperatureCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GeneralData, String> windLowCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GeneralData, String> windHighCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GeneralData, String> minUVICol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GeneralData, String> maxUVICol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GeneralData, String> minAQICol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GeneralData, String> maxAQICol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GeneralData, String> humidityCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GeneralData, String> snowFallCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GeneralData, String> pressureCol;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox Year;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox Type;

    private dbConnection dbconn;
    private ObservableList<GeneralData> data;
    private String sql = "SELECT * FROM weather_tracer";
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


        if (this.generalModel.isDatabasedConnected()) {

            this.dbStatus.setText("Connected to Database");
        } else {
            this.dbStatus.setText("Not Connected to Database");
        }
        Year.getItems().addAll("2018","2017","2016","2015","2014","2013");
        Type.getItems().addAll("Temperature","Pressure","UV","Humidity","Wind","Snow");

    }

    @FXML
    private void loadData(ActionEvent event)throws SQLException{
        try{
            Connection connection = dbconn.getConnection();
            this.data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                this.data.add(new GeneralData(rs.getString(1),
                        rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), 
                        rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), 
                        rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9),rs.getString(10), 
                         rs.getString(11), rs.getString(12)));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error " + e);
        }
        this.yearCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Year"));
        this.monthCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Month"));
        this.temperatureCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Temperature"));
        this.windLowCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Wind_Lowest"));
        this.windHighCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Wind_Highest"));
        this.minUVICol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("MinUVI"));
        this.maxUVICol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("MaxUVI"));
        this.minAQICol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("MinAQI"));
        this.maxAQICol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("MaxAQI"));
        this.humidityCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Humidity"));
        this.snowFallCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Snowfall"));
        this.pressureCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Pressure"));
        this.weatherTracerTable.setItems(null);
        this.weatherTracerTable.setItems(data);
    }

    @FXML
    private void search(ActionEvent event)throws SQLException {

        int max = Integer.parseInt(maxField.getText());
        int min = Integer.parseInt(miniField.getText());
        String selectedYear = (String) Year.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        String selectedType = (String) Type.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        String fsql = "SELECT * FROM weather_tracer";
        try {

            if (!(Type.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()) && !(Year.getSelectionModel().isEmpty())) {
                fsql = "SELECT * FROM weather_tracer where Year = " + selectedYear + " AND " + selectedType + " between " + min + " and " + max;
            } 
            else if (!(Type.getSelectionModel().isEmpty())) {
                fsql = "SELECT * FROM weather_tracer where " + selectedType + " between " + min + " and " + max;
            }
            Connection connection = dbconn.getConnection();
            this.data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(fsql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                this.data.add(new GeneralData(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9),rs.getString(10), rs.getString(11), rs.getString(12)));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error " + e);
        }
        this.yearCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Year"));
        this.monthCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Month"));
        this.temperatureCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Temperature"));
        this.windLowCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Wind_Lowest"));
        this.windHighCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Wind_Highest"));
        this.minUVICol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("MinUVI"));
        this.maxUVICol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("MaxUVI"));
        this.minAQICol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("MinAQI"));
        this.maxAQICol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("MaxAQI"));
        this.humidityCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Humidity"));
        this.snowFallCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Snowfall"));
        this.pressureCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GeneralData, String>("Pressure"));
        this.weatherTracerTable.setItems(null);
        this.weatherTracerTable.setItems(this.data);

    }
}
```

After I showed the demo, to my professor. He told me that I made some mistakes, because I combined all of the data into one relation. I need to separate it into different small relations. Now, I have 7 relations. Such as Air Quality Realtion, Humidity Relation, Snow Relation and etc...

I am trying to use a `NATURAL JOIN` for either one of the relations that I listed above and display them on the tableview. But I having trouble to do that,  because once I declared the tableview, I need to define the type and I can't alter the type afterward. Are there any ways to go around it?

Comment: You would need to provide some sample codes to demonstrate exactly where the problem is. In general, it does not matter how many `TableView`s you are populating from the database - it should work.

Comment: I uploaded it! Please take a look.

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: can't say anything to the sql portion (better split it out and ask a separate question) but on the fx side there are several issues, the main being the design/implementation of your data class (hint: please re-read your textbook and/or a basic tutorial about how to implement/name properties of a class such that PropertyValueFactory can do its job)

Comment: Why can't you modify your type just because you use it somewhere? Sure, you may need to adjust the second type parameters of the `TableColumn`s but unless you're planing to make your table editable or use custom `cellFactory`s, there shouldn't be an issue with leaving the second type parameter undpecified, i.e. `TableColumn<GeneralData, ?>`. BTW: Even though I recommend listening to your professor, make sure you understood him correctly. Imho it makes little sense to repeat the date in 7 tables. Are you sure he didn't try to tell you to move the db access to a seperate type?

Comment: @fabian thanks for your time! Does that mean I can leave the first parameter of TableColumn to be unspecified? Such as TableColumn<?,String>? Also to the tableView as  tableView<?>. I have done that and it gave me error because of ObservbleList.

Comment: If you use the renaming functionality your IDE should offer, there is no need to leave the first parameter open, even if you need to rename the type. You're able to use `?` for the second type parameter since you don't use members of `TableColumn` (except for the second type parameter of `PropertyValueFactory` which can be adjusted without issues) that use this type parameter. You use your `TableView`'s type parameter however when using `setItems` which uses the parameter type. Sure you could use the raw type, but I do not recommend this.

Comment: My intention is to display different relations in the same TableView. So I have tried to display air quality relation, and I would need to create a AirQualityData.java and I need to do TableView<AirQualtyData>, TableColumn<AirQualityData, String> and ObervbleList<AirQualityData> data to connect to Air Quality relation. But if I want to check Humidity(another relation) and display it’s data on the table. I need to create HumidityData and I can’t change the first parameter of TableView and TableColumn because I already declared them as AirQualtyData. Is there anyway around it?